# The file '' is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have a fairly simple silverlight application, in which I have databound a silverlight coverflow control to a simple list of images. This is working fine.

Further down the page I have another image, that I need databound to the same datacontext.

I am doing the following:
`<Border Name="DetailImage" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource FatBorderStyle}" Width="225" Height="225">`

```
                    <Border.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill">
                            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                        </ImageBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
```

However the line: `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>` - fails with the error in the headline. It is working fine in the other databinding in the page.

The datacontext of the page is set through code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I was just not properly awake :-D

I was trying in the failing line to actually databind incorrectly.

I just had to change the binding to this: `<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ElementName=HLARad, Path=SelectedItem.ImageSource}"/>`

See ya - until next time...